# Write to device characteristic in order to "authenticate", Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-ble, rxandroidble

I'm very new to RxAndroidBle and RxJava or RxKotlin.
I have a task somehow similar to this one, [How to receive all notifications in RxAndroidBle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192575/how-to-receive-all-notifications-in-rxandroidble)

I need to wirte to a characteristic in order to "authenticate" and be able to start receiveing notifications.

Somehow I'm not being able to pass the architecture of the accepted answer into kotlin.

Does someone can provide some insight? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm not able to pass the architecture of the accepted answer into kotlin."? Can you show an example of what you've tried / try to achieve?

Comment: Hi, after some work I manage to understand how rxJava works. Is working now! Thank you